# Unable to get transpose of a Matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Here is my file `training_new1.csv` (showing only two rows)

`PIDN,TMFI,Depth,Ca,P,pH,SOC,Sand
XNhoFZW5,1.6877,0.1907,0.0568,1,-0.2957,-0.0413,-1.1294
9XNspFTd,0.2702,0.2686,0.267,0,0.271,0.2723,0.2699`

I have the following MATLAB codes:

**Code1:**

```
x = dataset('file',['training_new1.csv'],'Delimiter',',');
x = single(x(:,2:end-5));

x' %print x transpose matrix
```

**Code2:**

```
x = dataset('file',['training_new1.csv'],'Delimiter',',');
x = x(:,2:end-5);

x' %print x transpose matrix -- this is NOT working
```

**My problem:** Code1 is working fine and Code2 shows following error:

```
Error using dataset.dataset>throwUndefinedError
Too many output arguments.

Error in  '  (line 472)
        function a = ctranspose(varargin), a = throwUndefinedError; end

Error in train (line 14)
x' %print x transpose matrix
```

I don't want to use [single()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/single.html) function to change the values in `x` to single point precision because I have already converted them in my input file `training_new1.csv`. What can I do to find out matrix `x'` in Code2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of printing x', I tried to print only x for both of your codes as follows.

code1 output:

```
1.6877    0.1907
0.2702    0.2686
```

code2 output:

```
TMFI      Depth 
1.6877    0.1907
0.2702    0.2686
```

Hope now you can understand the problem. You have texts in the matrix, hence you cannot find the transpose.

Then I edited code2 of yours as follows.

```
x = dataset('file',['training_new1.csv'],'Delimiter',',');
x = dataset2cell(x(:,2:end-5));
x = cell2mat(x(2:end,:));
x' %print x transpose matrix
```